# Does GMapEither type family example not really correspond Either intuition?

Tags: haskell, type-families

GHC User Guide shows this example in a [Data instance declarations](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#data-instance-declarations) section on Type Families:

```
data instance GMap (Either a b) v = GMapEither (GMap a v) (GMap b v)
```

I'm used that `Either` type is used whenever we want either left or right value, so I would expect `GMapEither` to somehow provide either left or right variant, but it seems it always holds both:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H

data family GMap k :: * -> *

data instance  GMap Int Int = GMapIntInt (H.HashMap Int Int)
                            deriving (Show, Eq)

data instance  GMap String Int = GMapStringInt (H.HashMap String
                                                  Int)
                               deriving (Show, Eq)

data instance  GMap (Either a b) v = GMapEither (GMap a v)
                                                (GMap b v)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let m = GMapIntInt H.empty
  print m
  let m2 = GMapStringInt H.empty
  print m2
  let m3 = GMapEither m m2
  let (GMapEither m3l m3r) = m3
  print m3l
  print m3r
```

Did I understand this correctly that it would be more appropriate to use a tuple here, for example like this:

```
data instance  GMap (a, b) v = GMapTuple (GMap a v) (GMap b v)
```

I think this might give a much better intuition.

Comment: "I would expect GMapEither to somehow provide either left or right variant" - this is the basis of your misunderstanding. `GMap k v` does not provide `k` - it consumes `k` to provide `v`. You give a `GMap (Either k0 k1) v` a value of type `Either k0 k1` and get a value of type `v` - this is `lookup`. (Aside: "I think this might give a much better intuition." - this is your 2nd fatal mistake. Programs are not written based on what is intuitively correct, but rather what is actually correct, according to a desired formal semantics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we make an abstraction, it usually has what's called a "semantic domain", which is the thing the abstraction is supposed to represent.  Properties of the abstraction should match the properties of the semantic domain. (When the abstraction has a type class, this has been called [type class morphism](http://conal.net/papers/type-class-morphisms/)).

`GMap` is clearly trying to represent some sort of mapping operation.  The prototypical example of a mapping is a function.  There are also finite maps like `Data.Map`, but it's kind of pretending to be a special sort of function also.

So anyway, we should expect `GMap a b` to have similar properties to functions `a -> b`.  If `GMap (a,b) v` is defined to be equal to `(GMap a v, GMap b v)`, then we should expect there to be a corresponding isomorphism in the semantic domain.  So just converting all the `GMap`s into function arrows `->`, we get:

```
f' :: ((a,b) -> v) -> (a -> v, b -> v)
g' :: (a -> v, b -> v) -> ((a,b) -> v)
```

`g'` is easy enough to get to typecheck, but there are two different implementations and no way to choose one:

```
g' :: (a -> v, b -> v) -> ((a,b) -> v)
g' = (tl, tr) (x,y) = tl x
-- and
g' = (tl, tr) (x,y) = tr y
```

and `f'` is downright impossible

```
f' :: ((a,b) -> v) -> (a -> v, b -> v)
f' t = (\a -> ??? , \b -> ???)
```

In the left `???`, we have an `a` and we need a `v`, but we can only construct a `v` if we give `t` both an `a` and a `b`, and we don't have anywhere to get the `b` we need.  The same thing happens in the right component of the tuple.

There's no clear way to go back and forth between a function from a pair `(a,b) -> v` and a pair of functions.  So to declare these two things equal as `GMap` seems incorrect.  The same thing happens with finite maps like `Data.Map` (you can get something to typecheck, but it won't end up being a true isomorphism because `f' . g' /= id` (or vice versa, I don't remember which)).

Whereas the isomorphism from `(Either a b -> v) -> (a -> v, b -> v)` is easy to write

```
f :: (Either a b -> v) -> (a -> v, b -> v)
f t = (t . Left, t . Right)

g :: (a -> v, b -> v) -> (Either a b -> v)
g (l, r) (Left x) = l x
g (l, r) (Right y) = r y
```

---

This semantic domain stuff can be a bit abstract for the down-to-earth programmer.  Why does it matter if we can write this isomorphism or not?  But you will see the problems quickly arise in a practical way when you try to make `GMap` do anything.

Let's start bundling the data family a couple of very simple operations we ought to be able to write:

```
class MapKey k where
    data family GMap k :: * -> *

    empty :: GMap k v
    lookup :: GMap k v -> k -> Maybe v
    insert :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v
```

And a very simple base case to work with

```
instance MapKey Int where
    data GMap Int v = GMapInt (Int -> Maybe v)
    empty = GMapInt (const Nothing)
    lookup (GMapInt f) x = f x
    insert x v (GMapInt f) = GMapInt (\y -> if x == y then Just v else f y)
```

If we try

```
instance (MapKey a, MapKey b) => MapKey (a,b) where
    data GMap (a,b) v = GMapTuple (GMap a v) (GMap b v)
    empty = GMapTuple empty empty
    lookup (GMapTuple l r) (x,y) =
        -- several implementations here, but maybe we could do
        lookup l x `mplus` lookup r y

    insert (x,y) v (GMapTuple l r) = GMapTuple (insert x v l) (insert y v r)
```

Seems reasonable, but it doesn't work

```
 >>> lookup (insert (1 :: Int, 2 :: Int) "value" empty) (1,3)
 Just "value"
```

that should have given `Nothing` because we inserted `(1,2)`, not `(1,3)`.  You could say that it's just a bug in my implementation, but I dare you to write a working one.

---

There's a beautiful correspondence between types and algebra that will guide you for how types ought to transform.  Here `~~` means "analogous to":

```
Either a b  ~~  a + b
(a,b)       ~~  a * b
a -> b      ~~  b ^ a
```

So

```
Map ((a,b) -> v) ~~ v^(a*b)
                  = (v^a)^b
                   ~~ Map b (Map a v)
```

That is, we should expect an isomorphism between maps from tuples and nested maps.  Similarly:

```
Map (Either a b -> v) ~~ v^(a+b)
                       = v^a * v^b
                        ~~ (Map v a, Map v b)
```

And there should be a nice isomorphism between maps from coproducts (`Either`) and pairs of maps.

This goes fascinatingly deep and it's worth playing around with what things are isomorphic to what other things.

Further reading:

- Chris Taylor, [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)
- Dan Piponi, [Memoizing Polymorphic Functions with High School Algebra and Quantifiers](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/11/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-with.html)
- Conal Elliott, [Denotational Design with Type Class Morphisms](http://conal.net/papers/type-class-morphisms/)

Comment: here they are https://gist.github.com/k-bx/193616185489ae63c337185e52182a00 No difference at all. Can you explain your thought a bit more please?

Comment: Oh, no I didn't mean using `GMap`, I mean using a represented map type like `Data.Map`, or even plain functions (`Map a b` = `a -> b`).  The data family is trying to imitate a normal map but more efficiently -- but if the abstraction is good, you should be able to convert back and forth between the inefficient representation.

Comment: @KostiantynRybnikov okay I updated with more of an explanation.  I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and a high-quality answer!